# Adding subelement in xml with integer value to a key

Tags: python

I want to assign a new sub element to an existing xml using element tree.

below original xml -

```xml
<FILE>
<INSTANCE>
    <A>123</A>
    <B>ABC</B>
</INSTANCE>
<INSTANCE>
    <A>456</A>
    <B>DEF</B>
</INSTANCE>
</FILE>
```

Below expected xml -

```xml
<FILE>
<INSTANCE>
    <A>123</A>
    <B>ABC</B>
    <C>0</C>
</INSTANCE>
<INSTANCE>
    <A>456</A>
    <B>DEF</B>
    <C>0</C>
</INSTANCE>
</FILE>
```

I tried this -

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse("test.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
s= {"":"0"}
c = root.makeelement("C",s)
for child in root.findall('.//INSTANCE/A/..'):
    child.append(c)
tree.write("test1.xml")
```

i got below output -

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to include the actual output as text rather than as an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start, Python Documentation for [ElementTree.makeelement](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.makeelement) says

> Do not call this method, use the SubElement() factory function instead.

So let's do that instead. And the solution is to set the text separately.

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse("test.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

for child in root.findall('.//INSTANCE/A/..'):
    c = ET.SubElement(child, "C")
    c.text = "0"   # SET the text explicitly

tree.write("test1.xml")
```

Finally, kindly edit your question and post the error output as text instead of an image.